Android Studio evaluate expression do not provide the result during debugging
I am currently using Android Studio version Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 1.
While debugging the application, when I tried to check the variable, the Evaluate Expression was working very slowly (~2 minutes) showing "Collecting data..."and after that did not get any result.
How we can solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.
